# Totem controls cannot be seen in fullscreen mode

Tags: totem

While playing videos using totem, the controls (as well as the mouse pointer) cannot be seen while switching to the fullscreen mode. However, if you hit "space", the video pauses and the controls appear. You can see the mouse pointer only when it hovers over the controls.

Should I report this as a bug or is there a way to rectify this?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/totem/+bug/989727

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reported a bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/totem/+bug/989727